# Scalamock 3. Mock overloaded method without parameter

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest, scalamock

I couldn't find any documentation that explains how to mock overloaded methods that take no arguments in scalamock e.g

```
public boolean isInfoEnabled(Marker marker);
public boolean isInfoEnabled();
```

To mock the function that takes the Marker, one can simply use

```
(loggerMock.isInfoEnabled(_: Marker)).expects(*).returning(true)
```

But how to mock the other method that takes no parameters? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
(loggerMock.isInfoEnabled: () => Boolean).expects().returning(true)
```

This [issue](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/94) helped me a lot. Still would be nice to have something like this documented.

Comment: This should definitely be documented. I spent about an hour looking for it. I'm considering submitting a pull request for it in the docs.

Comment: Great help. Lucky if was quite easy to find in google.

Answer (score 13):

In scala 2.12 this also works (no inspection for Intellij):

```
//noinspection ConvertibleToMethodValue
(tailer.run _: () => Unit) expects()
```

Answer (score 9):

I was using using this approach until I realised that in Scala 2.12+ this solution is deprecated.

You will get a warning like

```
Eta-expansion of zero-argument method values is deprecated.
```

After some researching I found out this solution:

```
(loggerMock.isInfoEnabled _ ).expects().returning(true)
```

or

```
import scala.language.postfixOps
loggerMock.isInfoEnabled _  expects () returning true
```

Comment: This does compile in 2.12+ 
NB: IntelliJ raises a bogus compile error in-line on it